# (Socket.io) - Why does socket object lose custom attributes on disconnect event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

On every new socket object(new connection) I set up custom attribute to socket object like this :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.username = "some-custom-username";
   console.log(socket.id); //Output : unique ID from socket object
   console.log(socket.username); //Output : some-custom-username


   socket.on('disconnect',function(reason){
      console.log(socket.id); //Output : Same unique ID like earlier
      console.log(socket.username); //Output : undefined
   });


}
```

**Can anyone explain why does this happen?**

It is same object, the id attribute stays the same but every custom attribute gets deleted on disconnect event therefore I am unable to easily detect which user has disconnected.